# How to move app one apple developer account to another account?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Now I could move apps from one apple developer account to another apple developer account.
But when I try to move I couldn't transfer some apps. I attached the image below. When I click the done button its redirect the app information pages.[image: devloper Apple account]

In one app I could able to move to further process but in another app I couldn't it redirect's to the app information page could anyone has the solution for this.?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because developer-centric questions about application stores are considered off-topic here on SO as discussed in [this meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272166/4667835).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove all builds and testers from Testflight to continue. (See the missing tick in the screenshot)

Comment: Sry I have founded answer. This is crt answer. Thanks for give an answer